# Plotting latitude and longitude with gmap as a background

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make a facebookish type profile page but using a gmap instead of an image.

I am using gmaps4rails to display the map and everything is displayed correctly with the code below.

```
<%= image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=1200x50&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{@user.latitude}%2C#{@user.longitude}" %>
```

When I add the map as a background-image it does not plot the @user.latitude/longitude. The map is displayed but the coordinates are not being plotted.

```
#cover_container{
overflow: auto;
width: 100%;
background-image: url("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=450x200&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{@user.latitude}%2C#{@user.longitude}");
}
```

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: whats the link with gmaps4rails? you use google maps static api

Comment: I was using it to display the this map for POC.

Comment: yes you were using it, but htere is no code relative to it anymore, I guess you can remove the tag